# Add chain link to my website

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to web development and I'm creating an intranet hub.  I need to create a chain link in my website using html, javascript or jquery.

I need to write inside a div where I am.  If I open loans, car loans, new cars I will show this in div: loans -> car loans -> new cars

How can I implement this with a simple html method?

```
 <a href=""> Loans </a>  ->  <a href=""> Car Loans </a> -> <a href=""> new cars
```

Comment: These sorts of links are called "breadcrumbs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being that you're asking how to do it with no indication of context, I would have to say that you're probably best sticking with plain html.

```
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;">
          <a href="link1">Link1</a> &gt;
          <a href="link2">Link2</a> &gt;
          <a href="link3">Link3</a> &gt;
          <a href="link4">Link4</a> &gt;
          <a href="link5">Link5</a>
    </div>
```

`&gt;` is the html entity for >

You can substitute `&gt;` with any html entity you like

output from above will look like this:
Link1 > Link2 > Link3 > Link4 > Link5

Answer (score 0):

***If*** I understand your question properly, you want a div (or div equivalent) that contains links and upon clicking, the resultant HTML shows up *inside that element*.
If that is the case, you are better off looking into using an `<iframe>`.

e.g.

```
<iframe src="panel.html">
</iframe>
```

Have it point to a html file containing your 3 links:

```
<a href="abc.html"> Loans </a>
<a href="xyz.html"> Car Loans </a>
<a href="123.html"> New cars </a>
```

Now clicking any of these links will open the relevant page inside the element.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for more information.

Comment: Looking @zzzzBov's comment to your question, it's quite possible that I _completely_ misunderstood your question...